# Regex extract mutliple values

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I have a string that looks like this: "60% Bob Peterson, 35% Jake Peter Sullivan, 5% Maria Teresa".

I want to write a regex to grab the first word after %:

Desired output: "Bob, Jake, Maria"

So far I came up with this: %\W*(\w+)

But it is only grabbing the first instance. I need to grab all instances and print them separated with a comma.

Comment: What tool or language are you using? The problem isn't your regex pattern; it's that your program isn't performing a global match.

Comment: I am using Tableau.

Comment: It looks like this might be a bug in Tableau, scroll down for the comment from the dev: https://community.tableau.com/s/idea/0874T000000HAFjQAO/detail

I'll tag this question with `tableau` so that people who know more about it might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python inside Tableau using TabPy

```
import re

string = "60% Bob Peterson, 35% Jake Peter Sullivan, 5% Maria Teresa"
result = re.findall(r'\d+%\s(\w+)', string)
print(', '.join(result))
```

In the tableau, you cant loop the regex check , hence use Python